# Requests - Python - Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, python-requests, request

I have a server running in Ubuntu OS, and I am using Python for getting to learn.

I started an app which I installed, When I opened the app in browser the page is not secure, like this -

[image: your image description goes here]

I am getting some data from this page using python -

```
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
import requests
requests.urllib3.disable_warnings(category=InsecureRequestWarning)
req = requests.get(url='https://127.0.0.1:7001', verify=False)
```

This shows an error -

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=7001): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by 
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fc2ae5f94f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

When I print the variable `req` to check the status, but python shows the variable is not defined

How to solve this, thanks

Comment: Can you print the url before calling requests library to see whether the url is correct or not?

Comment: @AnandTripathi, the url is https://127.0.0.1:7001/static/index.html#/, In the above image, the url shows different page in the localhost. I got the same error in all the pages in localhost

Comment: I meant in your program can you print url value. It seems from the logs that your url is pointing to some other ip address maybe your public ip address. Can you check that.

Comment: @AnandTripathi, I am sorry for this typeo error, I am copied the error from other server where I tried the same... I corrected the question. Please help, thanks

Comment: `url` isn't set in the code you shared. It surely is in the code you ran. Show how `url` is defined.

Comment: @theherk, I again run this above code and got the error, please take a look, thank you

Comment: And if you use the same url you used in the browser? Same?

Comment: @theherk, actually, when I use any page in that system[https:127.0.0.1:7001/xxxx], it shows the same error, the image is just for the reference

Answer (score 3):

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=443)

443 is the default port for HTTPS.

You're probably (we can't see how you've defined `url`, but that's my best guess) trying `https://127.0.0.1/...`, not `https://127.0.0.1:7001/...` – fix that in your code.

Comment: I am sorry for this typeo error, I am copied the error from other server where I tried the same... I corrected the question. Please help, thanks

Comment: If you're getting "Connection refused", it means there's nothing listening on that port.

Comment: I triple checked, the port is listening and actively running. Is this any firewall issue?

Comment: How did you test the port is available? Also, you claim you're using Ubuntu, yet your browser screenshot is obviously from Windows.

Comment: @M.K No, no it doesn't, unless you've somehow set up Microsoft ClearType font rasterization and are using the Windows Segoe UI font.